# Connecting Logstash to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-jdbc

When I start Logstash with my config file, the following error appears. I've added multiple classpaths to the current jdbc jar. Had the driver class been renamed or something? Thanks

```
[2018-09-11T11:44:57,241][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::Jdbc jdbc_connection_string=>"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/test?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=GMT&amp;DatabaseName=test", jdbc_driver_class=>"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver", jdbc_user=>"test", jdbc_password=><password>, statement=>"SELECT * FROM phones", id=>"d4c77c6d8f243cf0b447d00db3567bad38756544341a7e9fc53c5e611a6cec8d", enable_metric=>true, codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Plain id=>"plain_6b256972-6c6a-481a-87f0-8b587adf7e53", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8">, jdbc_paging_enabled=>false, jdbc_page_size=>100000, jdbc_validate_connection=>false, jdbc_validation_timeout=>3600, jdbc_pool_timeout=>5, sql_log_level=>"info", connection_retry_attempts=>1, connection_retry_attempts_wait_time=>0.5, parameters=>{"sql_last_value"=>1970-01-01 01:00:00 +0100}, last_run_metadata_path=>"C:\\Users\\ross.massie/.logstash_jdbc_last_run", use_column_value=>false, tracking_column_type=>"numeric", clean_run=>false, record_last_run=>true, lowercase_column_names=>true>
  Error: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver not loaded. :jdbc_driver_library is not set, are you sure you included
                  the proper driver client libraries in your classpath?
  Exception: LogStash::ConfigurationError
  Stack: C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:162:in `open_jdbc_connection'
C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc.rb:220:in `execute_statement'
C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:269:in `execute_query'
C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-input-jdbc-4.3.9/lib/logstash/inputs/jdbc.rb:255:in `run'
C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:512:in `inputworker'
C:/Program Files/logstash-6.3.2/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:505:in `block in start_input'
```

My config snippet:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/test?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=GMT&amp;DatabaseName=test"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files\logstash-6.3.2\lib\mssql-jdbc-7.0.0.jre8.jar"
    jdbc_user => "test"
    jdbc_password => "test123"

    statement => "SELECT * FROM phones"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "phones"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply made a custom bit of .NET coding to do the job rather than hooking them together like the official documentation suggests (badly).

I highly recommend everyone else do the same to save yourself the time I lost.